# Twitter OAuth asks twice for confirmation

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I wrote a script that asks Twitter for authorization. If the script runs the first time, it will be redirected to Twitter and then the credentials will be saved to a json file. This works. But the authorization page from twitter will be loaded two times. Perhaps somebody can help me to find the bug. Here is the script:

```
require('./vendor/autoload.php');

use TijsVerkoyen\Twitter\Twitter;

$twitter = new Twitter('xyz', 'xyz');
$response = $twitter->oAuthRequestToken('http://localhost:8888/tweeted-news/oauth-test.php');

$credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents('credentials.json'), true);

if (!isset($credentials['oauth_token'])) {
    $response = $twitter->oAuthAuthorize($response['oauth_token']);
    $response = $twitter->oAuthAccessToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
    file_put_contents('credentials.json', json_encode($response));
    var_dump('authorized');
} else {
    $twitter->setOAuthToken($credentials['oauth_token']);
    $twitter->setOAuthTokenSecret($credentials['oauth_token_secret']);
    var_dump('credentials');
}

var_dump($twitter->accountSettings());
```

I'm using this library https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/TwitterOAuth with composer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the else line. After the var_dump('authorized'), you should be setting the OAuthToken and OAuthTokenSecret. So the code should read:

```
if (!isset($credentials['oauth_token'])) {
    $response = $twitter->oAuthAuthorize($response['oauth_token']);
    $response = $twitter->oAuthAccessToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_GET['oauth_verifier']);
    file_put_contents('credentials.json', json_encode($response));
    var_dump('authorized');
    $twitter->setOAuthToken($credentials['oauth_token']);
    $twitter->setOAuthTokenSecret($credentials['oauth_token_secret']);
    var_dump('credentials');
}
```

Comment: I understand but I think I have to check the $_GET parameter, too Thanks

Comment: Yes. I was a little careless in the code. You should be checking $response after the call to oAuthAuthorize and OAuthAccessToken.